# parameterization of maven with persistence.xml is not work for hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, maven, tomcat7, jboss-seam

I have set up a profile in maven, for example

```
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
        <hibernate.search>//devserver/srchIndexes/</hibernate.search>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

in the `persistence.xml`, I have specified...

```
property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${hibernate.Search}" />
```

I just want to pass the server/folder location based on DEV/QA/Prod.

However when deploy the war to tomcat,
the hibernate search folder is created in the tomcat Folder as  `${hibernate.Search}`. Passing the value from maven to `xml` does not work.

I am using this command to to build the project.

```
mvn -Pdev install -DskipTests=true
```

Comment: hibernate.search (from the profile) != hibernate.Search (in persistence.xml). Names are case sensitive. Is that a typo in this question? If not, try making the names match to see if that helps.

Comment: found the issue, adding   <filtering>true</filtering> to the pom for the scr main resource fixed the problem

Comment: It is possible to answer your question yourself. Helpful for future readers.